# Redux+React manage state of two (or more) same elements. How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hello everyone) I can't understand how to manage state (open/closed) for two absolutely same elements (for example, datepicker- "start date" and "end date"). Now i made two action CHANGE_STATE1 and CHANGE_STATE2, but when i look at this code i'm going to frustration. 
And some examples for better understanding:
First popover and it's state:

```
<Popover open={this.props.isOpenPopoverLeft}>
```

And second popover:

```
<Popover open={this.props.isOpenPopoverRight}>
```

As you can see, elements absolutely identical, but has different state.
How to right beautiful code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact case (start and end pickers), and addressed it with an `edge` argument, referring to two constants, `START` and `END`.

Your action creator looks like:

```
setDate(edge, date)
```

Your React class might have a method like:

```
_onSelectDate(edge, date) {
  dispatch(setDate(edge, date));
}
```

and you can bind in the render method like

```
render() {
    // holds the state in an object like { start: true, end: false }
    const popoverState = this.props.popoverState;

    return (
      <div>

        <Popover open={ popoverState[START] }>
            <DatePicker
              onChange={ this._onSelectDate.bind(this, START) }/>
        </Popover>

        <Popover open={ popoverState[END] }>
            <DatePicker
              onChange={ this._onSelectDate.bind(this, END) }/>
        </Popover>

      </div>
    );

}
```

Depending on how similar the layouts are, you could also map over an array like `[START, END]`, or have a new component that takes `edge` as a prop.